# i have a problem installing anything in ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg, python3

```
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python3-apt (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apt.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apt.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-apt (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-software-properties:
 python3-software-properties depends on python3-apt (>= 0.6.20ubuntu16); however:
  Package python3-apt is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-software-properties (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-common:
 software-properties-common depends on python3-software-properties (= 0.96.20.8); however:
  Package python3-software-properties is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-apt
 python3-software-properties
 software-properties-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

these errors are there if i try to install anything 
so please help

Comment: A quick look at a package in your messages shows all supported release of Ubuntu (you didn't say your release of Ubuntu) are all good - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3-apt&searchon=names  -- have you `sudo apt -f install` yet?.  Your issue was created earlier (a prior command) that was not fixed, that you haven't told us about. Even if you don't remember it, your logs will remind tell you.

Comment: Do `sudo dpkg --audit`, this will show where the problem is. Then `dpkg --configure -a` and then `apt -f install`.

Comment: This duplicate flag is totally unreasonable. The "duplicate" questions have nothing to do with missing python3 package.